# Separate and combine code in Maple

Tags: include, maple, code-separation

I create simple package by using **table**. Because the package has many procedures so I ***split the code into many text file***. Each file will pass the convention checking of Maple

I want to create a master file and "include" all text-code file into master file before compiling.

```
restart;

HINHHOC9 := table():

$include <"D:/CaoHoc/LuanVan/Code/workspace/LuanVan/01_DocDuLieu.maple"> ;

url := currentdir();

save  HINHHOC9, cat(url, "/HINHHOC9.m");

libname := libname, url;

with(HINHHOC9);
```

---

But the master file compiled error

---

```
> restart;
> HINHHOC9 := table():
> 
on line 5 of "D:/CaoHoc/LuanVan/Code/workspace/LuanVan/00_MasterFile.maple",
syntax error, cannot open $include file:
"D:\CaoHoc\LuanVan\Code\workspace\LuanVan\01_DocDuLieu.maple":
$include <"D:/CaoHoc/LuanVan/Code/workspace/LuanVan/01_DocDuLieu.maple"> ;
^
> quit
memory used=0.6MB, alloc=6.3MB, time=0.14
```

Please help me to find out the way to include and compile the code

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have both quotation marks and angle brackets around the file name. You need one, but not both, of those.

Comment: I tried to use 
$include <"D:/CaoHoc/LuanVan/Code/workspace/LuanVan/01_DocDuLieu.maple"> ;
or $include "D:/CaoHoc/LuanVan/Code/workspace/LuanVan/01_DocDuLieu.maple" ;

But it still syntax error.